# Razor Partial View throwing Error unexpected <

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views, umbraco7

I have a razor Template which calls a partial view which in turns call another partial view.

Template -> Introduction Row (partial View) -> (partial views that are in that row) Slider Partial, Box 1 - 4 partials.

When I run the code I get an unhelpful error marked in the code below:
**INTRODUCTION ROW**

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
<div class="wrapper row3">
    <div id="container">
        <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
        <div id="homepage" class="clear">
            <div class="one_third first">
                <section class="main_slider">
                    @Html.Partial("IntroSlider")
                </section>


            </div>


            <div class="two_third">
                <div id="intro">
                    <ul class="nospace center clear">
                        <li class="one_quarter first">
                  <!-- THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN ON THE NEXT LINE -->
                            @Html.Partial("IntroBoxOne")
                        </li>
                        <li class="one_quarter">
                            @Html.Partial("IntroBoxTwo")
                        </li>
                        <li class="one_quarter">
                            @Html.Partial("IntroBoxThree")
                        </li>
                        <li class="one_quarter">
                            @Html.Partial("IntroBoxFour")
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am assuming the error is in the IntroBoxOne partial which follows:
**IntroBoxOne**

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage


<!--TODO: If no box'N'Content should we show the box at all? And if Not what size do we change any shown box to? -->
<article class="boxholder rnd8">

    <!-- Only show the top Image if one has been selected -->
    @{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@Umbraco.Field("topImageBoxOne").ToString()))
        {
            dynamic dynamicMediaItem = Umbraco.Media(Umbraco.Field("topImageBoxOne").ToString());
            <div class="push30"><img><img style="max-width:30px;max-height:30px;" src="@dynamicMediaItem.Url" alt="@Umbraco.Field("boxOneAltText")"></div>
        }
    }


    <!-- Only show the Image if one is selected -->

    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Umbraco.Field("boxOneIcon").ToString()))
    {
        dynamic dynamicMediaItem = Umbraco.Media(Umbraco.Field("boxOneIcon").ToString());
        <span class="push30"><img style="max-width:30px;max-height:30px;" src="@dynamicMediaItem.Url" alt="@Umbraco.Field("boxOneAltText")">@Umbraco.Field("boxOneTitle")</span>
    }

    <!-- Else only show the Title -->
    else
    {

    <span class="push30">@Umbraco.Field("boxOneTitle")</span>
    }


    <!-- Show the body content -->
    <p>@Umbraco.Field("boxOneContent")</p>

    <!-- Only show the button if has text. -->
    @{if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Umbraco.Field("boxOneIcon").ToString()))
    <footer><a href="#" class="button small gradient green rnd5">@Umbraco.Field("boxOneButtonText")</a></footer>
    }

</article>
```

Knowing me and knowing I haven't done this kind of coding in ages the error is probably in the @If else block but I have tried numerous things to sort it; all to no avail.

**UPDATE ONE:**

The error is definitely in this part of the code:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Umbraco.Field("boxOneIcon").ToString()))
    {
        dynamic dynamicMediaItem = Umbraco.Media(Umbraco.Field("boxOneIcon").ToString());
        <span class="push30"><img style="max-width:30px;max-height:30px;" src="@dynamicMediaItem.Url" alt="@Umbraco.Field("boxOneAltText")">@Umbraco.Field("boxOneTitle")</span>
    }

    <!-- Else only show the Title -->
    else
    {

    <span class="push30">@Umbraco.Field("boxOneTitle")</span>
    }
```

**UPDATE TWO:**

The Above IF ELSE statement throws an error but a double if statement like this succeeds:

```
@{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Umbraco.Field("boxOneIcon").ToString()))
        {
            dynamic dynamicMediaItem = Umbraco.Media(Umbraco.Field("boxOneIcon").ToString());
            <span class="push30"><img style="max-width:30px;max-height:30px;" src="@dynamicMediaItem.Url" alt="@Umbraco.Field("boxOneAltText")">@Umbraco.Field("boxOneTitle")</span>
        }

    <!-- Else only show the Title -->
    }

    @{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Umbraco.Field("boxOneIcon").ToString()))
        {
            <span class="push30">   @Umbraco.Field("boxOneTitle") </span>
        }

    <!-- Else only show the Title -->
    }
```

Clearly it is the syntax of the ELSE statement within the IF ELSE block that is wrong - but I have not found the solution other than two If statements.

Anyone spot the not so deliberate mistake?

Comment: Create an action that only renders the view causing the issue, in this case `IntroBoxOne`. You'll then be able to see where specifically the error comes from.

Comment: don't know if it helps, but if you are able to reach the code in debugging, then this means (according to my umbraco experience) that there is no error in the razor syntax, it must be a logic problem. If you are not able to reach a breakpoint in the razor code, then this means you have a razor or C# syntax issue. In other words, try adding a breakpoint and getting there, in case you do not succeed - then I was of no help - but in case you do, if I am right than you do not have an issue with the razor/C# syntax.

Comment: @Veverke The breakpoint is hit at the point the Exception is hit in the Introduction Row

Comment: No, that's not what I meant - once you run debugger, and an exception is thrown, regardless of whether you have a breakpoint or not the debugger will halt just at the exception being thrown. What I suggested was to add a breakpoint to the beginning of the partial, and then see if you reach it and can debug from there. If you do, I would assume (it's an assumption based in my experience working with umbraco... so far proved true) there are no C# syntax errors. Continuing debugging could prove fruitful. If you do not reach the breakpoint you just added - then you assured you have a syntax error.

Comment: Sometimes I happen to try to reach a breakpoint at the very first command of a partial and I can't. Then I figure out that there are syntax errors that are not/cannot be verified at compile time (frequently because we are working against "dynamic" types...). When I fix it, then I finally am able to reach my breakpoint at the beginning of the partial. In a short, I learned from this that if I can debug a partial I definitely have no razor syntax errors. But if I can't... than they might exist - or not.

Comment: Based on your update can you try removing sections inside the if/else to isolate the issue? Do you know for sure that Umbraco.Field("boxOneIcon") will return a value? If that returns null then the .ToString() will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the culprit here is the fact that your code reads:

```
@if (...) { ... }
<!-- Else only show the Title -->
else { ... }
```

and between `@if` and `else` blocks you should use C# comment syntax and not XML comment syntax. So this should fix the problem:

```
@if (...) { ... }
// Else only show the Title
else { ... }
```

Comment: You sir hit the nail on the head! What a silly mistake to make... Thanks for that.